# Remove Collection view bounce issue when using pull to refresh

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have one collection view configured as follow

```
        superCollectionView!.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
        superCollectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = false

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            superCollectionView!.refreshControl = refreshControl
        } else {
            superCollectionView!.backgroundView = refreshControl
        }
```

but bounce effect is still there.
I want to remove bounce from bottom...

Comment: then pull to refresh is not working

Comment: @Joe that prevents the scroll view to bounce from both sides (top and bottom) which leads to disable the refresh control.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove bouncing only from the bottom (For letting the `refreshControl` to be available), I'd suggest to handle it in [scroll​View​Did​Scroll:​](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll?language=objc) method to check if the scroll view `contentOffset.y` has been reached to bottom of the scroll view (logically, it is the content size of the scroll view minus the height of the visible frame of the scroll view), as follows:

**Solution:**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height), animated: false)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

After implementing `scroll​View​Did​Scroll` as mentioned above, it should be behaves like:

[image]

**Also:**

What about achieving the opposite?

Referring to the above description, *preventing the top bouncing* would be:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0), animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: not working when superCollectionView is having child collection views